# Inserting a Javascript snippet into PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to insert a small live support chat widget from purechat.com into my Oxwall website, and I'm a bit lost about integrating Javascript into a PHP document.

Here's the Purechat widget code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>(function () { var done = false; var script = document.createElement('script'); script.async = true; script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.src = 'https://www.purechat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetScript'; document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0).appendChild(script); script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function (e) { if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) { var w = new PCWidget({ c: '3c99852c-1f1a-4a5a-8061-f987c9998d6d', f: true }); done = true; } }; })();</script>
```

For some reason, I can't seem to post the PHP code in here without it going all wonky, but I posted the site code at www.whiskerkiss.net/sitecode.txt

I would like to thank you in advance for any help you can give me on this.

Comment: It seems like you use a framework, which one is it?

Comment: PHP: serverside, generates your output which is sent to the Browser (clientside) where your JS will be executed. Normally just use http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php but you seem to use some Framework so you will have to look for help there (or with those tags)